# NSAttributedString method return Nil

Tags: xamarin.ios

In xamarin.ios ,i'm implementing a method like this:

```
  public void SetHtml(string htmlText)
    {
       var err = new NSError();
       var atts = new NSAttributedStringDocumentAttributes
       {
           DocumentType = NSDocumentType.HTML,
           StringEncoding = NSStringEncoding.UTF8,
       };
       AttributedText = new NSAttributedString(NSData.FromString(htmlText), atts, ref err);
    }
```

But in some cases, in some traces i got this error:

**Could not initialize an instance of the type "Foundation.NSAttributedString": The native 'initWithData:options:documentAttributes:error:' method returned nil.**

I've tried to make the atts null, but there is no problem when i got an instance from NSAttributedString, what can be the problem?

Comment: It's failable `init`, if something happens, it returns `nil` and error would be in `ref error`. Can you add the string in `htmlText` that causes failure in the question?

Comment: "<span style = \"font-family:sans-serif; font-size:11pt; color:RGB(166,166,166); \">hey <font color='#0062AE'>Jude</font></span>"

Comment: Why is the first back slash outside the quotes "\"? Should it be this instead? `<span style = "\font-family:sans-serif; font-size:11pt; color:RGB(166,166,166); \">hey <font color='#0062AE'>Jude</font></span>`